# remove characters that are not present in two strings

Tags: javascript, string, format, set

I have two strings, one is a mask which can change and the other one is a users input.

I need to keep the mask format and remove numbers that are not present in both strings

```
rawValue: "25155122"
value: "2 5155 1220 0000"
```

I have for example these two strings, the expected outcome would be this:

```
 newValue = "2 5155 122" <= 
the zeros are removed as they are a mask and user has not typed in the rest of the numbers yet
```

This is what i've tried so far:

```
const strSet = str => new Set(str.split(''));
const setDiff = (a, b) => new Set(Array.from(a).filter(item => !b.has(item)));
const prune = (str, set) => str.split('').filter(x => set.has(x))
  .join('');


  const diff = setDiff(strSet(rawValue), strSet(value));
  const a1 = prune(value, diff);
  const b1 = prune(rawValue, diff);
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not certainly sure what exactly you want, but hopefully this resolves your issue...

```js
const rawValue = "25155122"
const value = "2 5155 1220 0000" 

//convert string value of rawValue into an array
const rawValueArray = rawValue.split("");

//converts string value of Value into an array
const valArray = value.split("");

//filters out array value in VALUE that's not included in RAWVALUE
const newArray = valArray.filter(val => rawValueArray.includes(val));

console.log("new_value_without_spaces", newArray.join(""))

//filters out array value in VALUE that's not included in RAWVALUE and also ignores the spaces
const newArrayWithSpaces = valArray.filter(val => val === " " || rawValueArray.includes(val));

console.log("new_value_with_spaces", newArrayWithSpaces.join(""))
```

Comment: This works nearly perfectly! thank you so much, the only issue if the user (var value) types in 25 and then 0 it automatically adds the rest of 0000.

So for example my value (mask is): 

000 000 000

and the user types in 125 0, it automatically adds: 125 000 000
 if you understand what i'm saying

Comment: yeah I understand, you want to get rid of the automatic Zeros being added even when the user doesn't fill up the 000 000 000 expected number...how are you converting the raw value (user input) into your value(one adding all the zeros)

Comment: yes exactly, the main point is so that I keep the spaces where they need to be, so if the mask given is 07 225 552, if the user enters 15 2 it should not add the rest: 15 225 552 it should only keep the 15 2 and let the user enter the rest, not sure how i could achieve this

Comment: would appreciate some help if you have any :)